# I am trying to display a product Image that I have saved to the database in a SpringBoot application. When displaying in my front end Image is blank

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

The image is saving to the database no problem but when trying to display in my front end I am getting blank Images. I also am struggling to understand the logic in how the Image is saving. I have it saved in /user-photos, you will see in my code that the path is this: /user-photos/" + "0" + "/" + image; at first the zero was id as I thought that's how it would save but I noticed they were all saving to /user-photos/0 but either way the image is not displaying - here is my code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "msItem")
public class Item {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long itemId;
@Column(nullable = false, length = 45)
private String itemName;
@Column(nullable = false)
private int itemPrice;
@Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
private String itemDesc;
@Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
private String category;
@Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
private String image;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private User user;

@Transient
public String getPhotosImagePath() {

    return "/user-photos/" + "0" + "/" + image;
}

@PostMapping("/products/save")
public String itemAdd(Item item,  @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile, Principal principal, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws IOException {
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(principal.getName());
    item.setUser(user);
    String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
    item.setImage(fileName);
    String uploadDir = "user-photos/" + item.getItemId();

    FileUploadUtil.saveFile(uploadDir, fileName, multipartFile);
    itemRepository.save(item);


    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Product Listed for sale");
    return "home_page";
}

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {


@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    exposeDirectory("user-photos", registry);
}

private void exposeDirectory(String dirName, ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    Path uploadDir = Paths.get(dirName);
    String uploadPath = uploadDir.toFile().getAbsolutePath();

    if (dirName.startsWith("../")) dirName = dirName.replace("../", "");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/" + dirName +   "/**").addResourceLocations("file:/"+ uploadPath + "/");
}
}



In the html page: 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>List products</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {
background-image: url('MarketSwipe.png');
background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container text-center">

<div th:if="${message}" class ="alert alert-success text-center">
    [[${message}]]
</div>
<div>
    <h2>Manage My Products</h2>
</div>

<div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>$ Price</th>
            <th>Manage Product</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="item: ${listItems}">
            <td> <img th:scr="${item.photosImagePath}"      style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></td>
            <td th:text="${item.itemName}">Name</td>
            <td th:text="${item.itemDesc}">Description</td>
            <td th:text="${item.itemPrice}">Price</td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-primary mt 4"   th:href="@{'/products/update/' + ${item.itemId}}">Update</a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger"   th:href="@{'/products/delete/' + ${item.itemId}}">Delete</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we see the template for the page?

Comment: @egeorge Hi there, I have edited so you can see the page template

Answer (score 0):

you have mentoned this as scr, instead of src

```
th:src="${item.photosImagePath}"
```

Comment: I Have it like that already? : td> <img th:scr="${item.photosImagePath}" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">.  </td>

Comment: Check the code you had it like th:scr,it must be th:src

Comment: I have updated the question with how I have the template, Could you please take a look